# How many platonic solids do exist in non-euclidean space?

Tags: geometry, noneuclidean-geometry, platonic-solids

The [proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platonic_solid#Geometric_proof) that there exists only five platonic solids assumes that the angle between the adjacent sides must be less than 360°, because otherwise the surfaces would be flat or even overlap. However this proof doesn't seem to work in non-euclidean space, because the sum of angles of the sides to generate a "flat" surface could be higher or lower than 360°.

Does this mean that the number of platonic solids in non-euclidean or curved space could be different from five?

Comment: How do you define "platonic solid" in non-euclidean space?

Comment: How do you define "non-euclidean space"?  Did you envision that the space could be an arbitrary manifold (of real dimension 3), or is the restriction narrower (e.g. to constant curvature space)?

Comment: I was actually thinking only of constant curvature space. I guess for an arbitrary manifold things might become quite messy, given that curvature and the sum of angles can be different at each vertex.

Comment: The so-named "non-Euclidean" geometries are specifically those which have a different axiom of parallelism from Euclid's. They all have constant curvature. They comprise the hyperbolic and elliptic geometries. Is this effectively what you mean?

Comment: Yes, I meant  "how many platonic solids exist in hyperbolic or elliptic space?"